# How to compare two OrderedDict dictionaries?

Tags: python

How can I compare two OrderedDict dictionareis?

My structure is the following:

```
dict_a = OrderedDict([(1,4), (2,5), (3,3), (4,5), (5,4), (6,4), (7,4), (8,3), (9,4)])

dict_b = OrderedDict([(1,4), (2,2), (3,1), (4,4), (5,6), (6,7), (7,4), (8,2), (9,5)])

for values in score_dict.items():
if values == course_dict.values():
    print 'match!'
else:
    print 'No match!'
```

It iterates through and both lists are ordered so it should match on 1 and 7?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Got it to work with Simeon's solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `items()` and the built-in `zip()` function:

```
for i, j in zip(dict_a.items(), dict_b.items()):
    if i == j:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
(1, 4)
(7, 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the intersected elements that are the same at each ordered location:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dict_a = OrderedDict([(1,4), (2,5), (3,3), (4,5), (5,4), (6,4), (7,4), (8,3), (9,4)])
>>> dict_b = OrderedDict([(1,4), (2,2), (3,1), (4,4), (5,6), (6,7), (7,4), (8,2), (9,5)])
>>> [i1 for i1, i2 in zip(dict_a.iteritems(), dict_b.iteritems()) if i1 == i2]
[(1, 4), (7, 4)]
```

If you don't care about ordering:

```
>>> set(dict_a.items()).intersection(set(dict_b.items()))
set([(7, 4), (1, 4)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for x in dict_a.items():
    if x in dict_b.items():
        print(x)


(1, 4)
(7, 4)
```

Comment: These are dicts. There's no need for a O(n**2) solution here.

Comment: This doesn't preserve ordering though - not sure if that's what OP wanted or not

Comment: @jterrace: Yes it does. The result of `items()` is ordered.

Comment: No, but it would match an item x in location i that is not in location i in the other dict

Comment: @jterrace: "Items" of a dictionary are key, value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the items and print it if you find them equal.

```
In [10]: for a, b in zip(dict_a.items(), dict_b.items()):
   ....:     if a == b:
   ....:         print True
   ....:     else:
   ....:         print False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert OrderDict().items() to a set and use set arithmetic. Set arithmetic is pretty powerful and intuitive once you understand the basics.

```
In [39]: set_a = set(dict_a.items())

In [40]: set_b = set(dict_b.items())

In [41]: set_a.intersection(set_b) # items in a and b
Out[41]: {(1, 4), (7, 4)}

In [42]: dict(set_a.intersection(set_b)) # if you need to move back to a dict
Out[42]: {7: 4, 1: 4}

In [43]: set_a - set_b # stuff in set a but not in b
Out[43]: {(2, 5), (3, 3), (4, 5), (5, 4), (6, 4), (8, 3), (9, 4)}

In [44]: set_b - set_a # stuff in set b but not in a
Out[44]: {(2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 4), (5, 6), (6, 7), (8, 2), (9, 5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want both keys and values to match, but are not concerned about position within each `OrderedDict`:

```
for k, v in dict_a.items():
  if v == dict_b[k]:
    print '(%s, %s)' % (k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include index in the OrderedDict as a part of the comparison:

```
>>> [a[0] for a, b in zip(dict_a.items(), dict_b.items()) if a == b]
[1, 7]
```

If you want to get all keys that have the same value in both of the OrderedDicts, regardless of order:

```
>>> [k for k, v in dict_a.items() if k in dict_b and dict_b[k] == v]
[1, 7]
```