# Inconsistent behavior when trying to sort deep nested structures in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sorting, nested

I am trying to sort deep nested list or dictionary structures in Python 3 where the built-in sorted function cannot compare different object types, as it can Python 2. I got my solution working and I am getting expected result most of the time, however I have inconsistent behavior in one of my tests which attempts to deep sort a dictionary object. Sometimes when I run the code bellow the assertion passes and sometimes it fails to sort the inner list dictionary items:

```
OrderedDict([('journeys', [None, OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('passengers', [1, 2]), ('price', 100)]), OrderedDict([('id', 3), ('passengers', [1, 2]), ('price', 200)]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('passengers', [3, 4]), ('price', 150)])])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 90, in <module>
    assert new_lst == result
AssertionError
```

I have been looking at my code but I cannot figure out what goes wrong as it looks like a behavior that can happen when working with processes or threads, however this is not the case. If you wonder this is still draft code for porting Python 2.x code do Python 3.x and the "sorted" function incompatibility problem comes into play when trying to sort deeply nested structures of different built-in data types. I am using the visitor pattern to walk over all nodes recursively and I am using predefined rules (`self.data_weights`) to sort different built-in data types.

I am dead stuck at the moment and any help in figuring out what is wrong with the code below is highly appreciated.

I am executing the code with :

> Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
>   [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
>
> **Update**: My tests are passing consistently with Python 3.6.2 (see python version bellow). The strange behavior I experience happens with Python 3.4.3. Any ideas?
>
> Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 20 2017, 08:43:29) 
>   [GCC 4.9.4] on linux

```
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict

class NodeVisitor:
    def visit(self, node):
        methname = 'visit_' + type(node).__name__
        meth = getattr(self, methname, None)
        if meth is None:
            meth = self.generic_visit
        return meth(node)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        raise RuntimeError('No {} method'.format('visit_' + type(node).__name__))


class Evaluator(NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_types = ["NoneType", "int", "float", "bool",
                           "str", "tuple", "list", "dict"]

    def sort_node(self, node):
        self.data_weights = collections.OrderedDict((i, []) for i in self.data_types)
        for elem in node:
            try:
                self.data_weights[type(elem).__name__].append(elem)
            except KeyError:
                print (('Encountered unsuported data type "{}". \
                         Ignoring it!').format(type(elem).__name__))
                continue
        for k, v in self.data_weights.items():
            if k != 'dict':
                v.sort()
            else:
                v.sort(key=lambda x: str(x))
        result = []
        for v in self.data_weights.values():
            if v:
                for item in v:
                    result.append(item)
        return result

    def generic_visit(self, node):
            return node

    def visit_tuple(self, node):
        sorted_node = self.sort_node(node)
        return tuple(self.visit(elem) for elem in sorted_node)

    def visit_str(self, node):
        return ''.join(sorted(node))

    def visit_list(self, node):
        sorted_node = self.sort_node(node)
        return [self.visit(elem) for elem in sorted_node]

    def visit_dict(self, node):
        sorted_node = self.sort_node(node)
        return collections.OrderedDict((k, self.visit(node[k])) for k in sorted_node)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    alist ={
    'journeys': [
    {'id': 1, 'passengers': [1, 2], 'price': 100},
    {'id': 3, 'passengers': [2, 1], 'price': 200},
    {'id': 2, 'passengers': [4, 3], 'price': 150},
    None,
    ]
    }

    new = Evaluator()
    new_lst = (new.visit(alist))
    print (new_lst)

    expected = OrderedDict([
    ('journeys', [
    None,
    OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('passengers', [1, 2]), ('price', 100)]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('passengers', [3, 4]), ('price', 150)]),
    OrderedDict([('id', 3), ('passengers', [1, 2]), ('price', 200)])
    ])
    ])
    assert new_lst == expected
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two OrderedDict dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961087/how-to-compare-two-ordereddict-dictionaries)

Comment: I am converting dictionaries to orderedDictionaries after sorting them, but I am not comparing orderedDictionaries so I believe it is not the same.

Comment: The issue might be that you can't compare lists to an OrderedDict objects using the `==` operator, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: The  == operator in the assert statement is comparing OrderedDict to OrderedDict objects. I have unit tests that use self.assertEqual to do the same comparison and I have the same behavior - sometimes they pass sometimes they do not.

Comment: before the `assert`, inspect the contents of each `OrderedDict`: `print new_lst;
    print expected`, compare, they don't match

Comment: Yes sometimes the returned values match sometimes they do not that is what the problem consists of. I cannot explain the inconsistent behavior as I am not using threads or processes to handle different tasks so I should be getting stable results ...

Comment: Why are you sorting by `str` outputs, and why are your inputs using regular dicts instead of OrderedDicts?

Comment: I don't understand what you are seeing but there is some chance it is related to hash randomisation.  Could you try with PYTHONHASH set to a fixed value?

Comment: Also can you tell us how the dictionaries differ when the assert fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is causing your assert failure: I haven't found the specific compare that can sometimes be False.  But I think it might be caused by this line:

```
v.sort(key=lambda x: str(x))
```

where you use the `str` of a value that is a `dict` to sort your data.

In any case, the symptoms suggest to me that it is caused by Python's specified non-determinism in the order of iteration over dictionaries.

In Python 2.7, if you iterate over a dictionary (including, for example, by calling `str` on it) then you will get an arbitrary ordering.  However, that ordering will always be the same whenever the same dictionary is constructed in the same way, with the same sequence of inserts and deletes.

For Pythons 3.3 to 3.5 that was no longer true.  Because of the introduction of hash randomisation by default, successive invocations of Python could change that ordering for the dictionary even though it was constructed in the same way.  The ordering would be consistent during the lifetime of a single interpreter but could change next time it was run.

In Python 3.6 that changed again.  Dictionaries now preserve the order in which they are constructed and iteration is always in that order.

So I *suspect* that your test is sensitive to the order of iteration of a dictionary and that is giving the inconsistent results you see.

Comment: Hi strubbly,
v.sort(key=lambda x: str(x)) is the problem with inconsistency.
v = sorted(v, key=lambda x: str(x)) fails everytime.